# How can I make this animation on scroll from the middle of the screen, not the top as it currnetly is?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As title, I want this exact code to work, but the animation to trigger when the middle of the screen hits if possible.

If the middle is not possible, then the bottom would be better.

Thanks!

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $(".animation-test").each(function () {
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
        var imageHeight = $(this).height();
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (
            imagePos < topOfWindow + imageHeight &&
            imagePos + imageHeight > topOfWindow
        ) {
            $(this).addClass("slideRight");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("slideRight");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.element-to-hide {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.slideRight {
    visibility: visible;
    animation-name: slideRight;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
@keyframes slideRight {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 900px"></div>
<div class="animation-test element-to-hide">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur in,
        non blanditiis error debitis optio exercitationem incidunt deleniti ex
        recusandae eligendi. Reiciendis cupiditate quibusdam odio perferendis.
        Facilis fugiat ab molestiae.</h1>
</div>
<div style="height: 900px"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ch9xn70/5/

Comment: If you do this, the item will disappear as soon as you scroll passed the exact middle. Is there any way to widen that window so it you will trigger the animation as you hit the middle but not have it disappear as soon as you leave it?

http://jsfiddle.net/uLtbep72/

Comment: Also, just for clarity.. what would be the code to switch it to the bottom instead of the top?

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the half viewport height from the `imagePos`.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".animation-test").each(function() {
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
    var imageHeight = $(this).height();
    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
    const heightHalf = $(window).height() / 2;

    if (
      imagePos - heightHalf < topOfWindow + imageHeight &&
      imagePos - heightHalf + imageHeight > topOfWindow
    ) {
      $(this).addClass("slideRight");
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("slideRight");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.element-to-hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.slideRight {
  visibility: visible;
  animation-name: slideRight;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes slideRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 900px"></div>
<div class="animation-test element-to-hide">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur in, non blanditiis error debitis optio exercitationem incidunt deleniti ex recusandae eligendi. Reiciendis cupiditate quibusdam odio perferendis. Facilis fugiat ab molestiae.</h1>
</div>
<div style="height: 900px"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Check it in action on Codepen](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/XWpdgyw)